# how to produce output string and numbering from the same statement in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to produce output string and numbering from the same statement in python?eg. "output_CH = 0.7 and CH_healthy"

```
if input_CH in range (185, 211):
if input_CH >= 185 and input_CH < 190:
    output_CH = (1/5 * input_CH) - 37            
elif input_CH >= 190 and input_CH <= 200:
    output_CH = 1   
else: 
    output_CH = (-1/10 * input_CH) + 21

output_CH = "CH_healthy"
```

Comment: Edit question to format code properly and to explain your problem.

Comment: Do you want to have a `tuple`? `output_CH = (0.7, "CH_healthy")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You question is apparently not clear but I am assuming that you want `output_CH` to hold two values. So you can go ahead and try out the following code

```py
if input_CH in range (185, 211):
    if input_CH >= 185 and input_CH < 190:
        output_CH = (1/5 * input_CH) - 37
    elif input_CH >= 190 and input_CH <= 200:
        output_CH = 1
    else:
        output_CH = (-1/10 * input_CH) + 21

output_CH = list(output_CH)
output_CH.append('CH_healthy')
output_CH = tuple(output_CH)
print(output_CH)
```

All I have done is first calculated the value of `output_CH` and then converted it to a list and the I append "CH_healthy" to it, then converted it to a `tuple` since it is immutable and take up less memory.

### Alternate:

```py
if input_CH in range (185, 211):
    if input_CH >= 185 and input_CH < 190:
        output_CH = (1/5 * input_CH) - 37
    elif input_CH >= 190 and input_CH <= 200:
        output_CH = 1
    else:
        output_CH = (-1/10 * input_CH) + 21

output_CH = "{} and CH_healthy".format(output_CH)
print(output_CH)
```

Here, I have simply inserted the previous value in the new string along with `CH_healthy`.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: yes. i want it to hold two values. i've tried your code but there's an error. hmm 'int' object is not iterable.

Comment: @nadya you tried the first or second one? and what value is stored in input_CH?

Comment: yeay haha the alternative answer is work out :) THANKYOU so much :D

Comment: @nadya glad I could help. Cheers :)

Comment: but i have another problem where if the output is float, it will not produce 0. i still try to find solution for that one

Comment: could you please elaborate the problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203265/discussion-between-nadya-and-debdut-goswami).

Answer (score 0):

Use string interpolation in your last assignation for output_CH:

```
if input_CH in range (185, 211):
    if input_CH >= 185 and input_CH < 190:
        output_CH = (1/5 * input_CH) - 37
    elif input_CH >= 190 and input_CH <= 200:
        output_CH = 1
    else: 
        output_CH = (-1/10 * input_CH) + 21
output_CH = f"output_CH = {output_CH} and CH_healthy"
print(output_CH)
```

This way if input_CH = 186 you get "output_CH = 0.20000000000000284 and CH_healthy"

The key is the "f" before you string assignation. See [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) for the docs.